# Testing the coefficients of the same linear regression model during two distinct time frames

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression

I searched for this question in the forum but couldn't find any prior posts that match my question. I am currently working on a linear regression model that has 5 independent variables (metric values and dummy variables for categorical values) and 1 dependent, metric variable.

Now, I would like to test whether there have been any **significant changes in the coefficients of my independent variables during the two different time frames** (one pre-Covid from 1991- Jan 2020 and one from Feb 2020- up to now).

What would be the most appropriate way to go about this? I would guess that just running the same regression during two different time frames is not the right choice, or is it?

Comment: Introduce a dummy representing the two time periods, and interact it with the variables you think *might* change effect ...

Comment: Many thanks! Will give it a try